# using radiobutton group to open new activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, radio-button

I have a group of 4 radiobuttons to select which activity to open when a button is pressed, I have tried the code below for 2 of the radiobuttons, but it is not functioning as intended. I'm completely new to java so any help would be great, thanks!

```
public class ModeSelect extends ActionBarActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mode_select);

   // Button OpenChannel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OpenChannelMode0);
    RadioButton SPIM = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.SPIMaster);

    SPIM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    Button OpenChannel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OpenChannelMode0);

    OpenChannel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ModeSelect.this, SPIOptions.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
        }
    });

    RadioButton I2CM = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.I2CMaster);

    I2CM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Button OpenChannel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OpenChannelMode0);

            OpenChannel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ModeSelect.this, I2COptions.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: and what exactly is not working?

Comment: first of all, don´´t initialize Your button OpenChannel in that way, do it before using the radio buttons. Then, at OpenChannel button click, check which radio button is checked and open the activity You want for the radio button..

Comment: how do I check which radio button is checked?

Comment: if (radiobutton.checked == "true")

Comment: i know its something like that in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this manner

```
 Button OpenChannel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OpenChannelMode0);

    OpenChannel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(radiobuttonObj1.isChecked()){
                //open activity 1
            }else if(radiobuttonObj2.isChecked()){
                //open activity 2
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i only want the activity to change when the button is pressed, i've tried putting the button click listener code in the first case but its throwing unexpected token errors

Comment: can you share the full exception log?

Comment: Button OpenChannel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OpenChannelMode0);

        OpenChannel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ModeSelect.this, SPIOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

Comment: basically im putting that into the first case its probably the wrong way to go about it

Comment: basically you trying to achieve is when a particular radio button is selected and on button tap, a activity should open?

Comment: thanks a lot, I had tried this but had checked instead of ischecked. is there a reference with all the methods for java anywhere on the web?